# Laravel mix doesn't see img elements in vue components

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-mix

Laravel Mix moves images that used in scss from resources folder to public folder, but doesn't moves images from src attribute of img tags that I use in my vuejs components...

```
<img src="images/logo.png" >
```

What I have to do?

Comment: What is the request in your network tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to 
`<img src="./images/logo.png" >`

### Edit

The image tag should be , considering the relative path from `resouces/assets/js/components/Example.vue` to `resources/assets/img/logo.jpg`.

Comment: I would recommend to put the logo in `/public/img` and use an absolute path to it
 
`<img src="/img/logo.png" >`

Comment: `ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                  

This relative module was not found:

* ./images/logo.png in ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-42bd4064"}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./resources/assets/js/views/Home.vue`

Comment: @fiter, you have to write the relative path to the component file to the image. Let's say the component is in `resources/assets/js/components` and the image is in `resources/assets/images`. You will write `<img src="../../images/logo.jpg">`

Comment: @fiter, glad I could help. I updated my answer to reflect the complete solution, please accept it to mark the question as solved.